# highlight a complete row using jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to highlight complete row, but some how i could only highlight a column but not a row. I tried using parent() but nothing really helping me out. please find my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Admin/IT/operations/Documents/jquery.SPServices-0.5.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
//alert("alert test");
/*$Textsql = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Budakov')"); 
$Textsql.css("background-color", "#461B7E"); */


$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetListItems",
  async: false,  
  listName: "OnCallList",

  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    //alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function() {      
     var TextList=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
     $Textsql = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('" + TextList.toString() + "')"); 

    $Textsql.css("background-color", "#A9A9A9"); 

  });
}
});
});
</script>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$Textsql = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('" + TextList.toString() + "')").closest('tr');
```

Note that if you have a background colour set on the cells, setting the `tr` background colour may have no effect.

Note also that `$()` is deprecated functionality, and your code will break if you upgrade to jQuery 1.4.  Use `$(document)` instead, or simply enclose your entire function: `$(function() { /* onready code */ });`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's not working for me. any other suggestions?

Comment: @user Not without seeing your HTML and knowing what `SPServices` is.

Comment: I have updated my code above, and I am trying to use jquery to highlight the row. Spservices is Jquery library for sharepoint webservices. Using this I am trying to read the sharepoint list and compare with list on the page and highlight the row when there is a matching record.

Comment: @user It's impossible to answer this question from the JS alone. You need to provide (a) the HTML of the table and (b) a sample response from the AJAX request.  If you could clarify what is working and what isn't (and perhaps link to a working example) I may be able to help.